# Timeline profiler requires a development or profiling build of react-dom@^18

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I believe 17.0.2 is the latest release, or is there also a version 18? Anyone know how to get timeline profiling working on Chrome?

Chrome version: 99.0.4844.84 (Official Build) (x86_64)
Devtools version: 4.24.0 (3/10/2022)

[Timeline profiler requires a development or profiling build of react-dom@^18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxXWL.png)

Comment: Hey, Thomas.
Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Nope, but since React 18 is released, maybe that version will indeed enable timeline profiling. Haven't tried it though.